# Fill fields in PDF with python from final product of Model Builder

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, pdf, dbf

I am trying to fill a PDF file from a Excel file data produced by a Model Builder after GIS processing with ArcMap. I am using the Python language.

I consider that using a PDF form is the most appropiate way to carry out this task (use the Excel values to fill the fields of the PDF form)

I show an image of what I am trying to do. The reason to use python (I saw a code in VB) is that I want to connect the script of Model Builder with the script of this task (reading excel file and export values to the PDF form)

Which Python packages are the most suitable for this task?
[image]

Comment: If you are sure that arcpy can't help, then having it in your title is confusing.

Comment: Please expand more what you mean by "gaps between text already written"?  Is the pdf being exported from a layout view?  Is this a text element or something else?  I would also suggest updating question and include a screen capture showing an example of the gap text.

Comment: Sorry. I ll make the changes.

Comment: so essentially you want to paste values from an excel table to a PDF?

Comment: and are you merging the to be created PDF to a PDF map? are you iterating this task for multiple uses? or is this a one time thing?

Comment: in the same script, importing arcpy and other packages, to run all the task (the model translated to python and the pdf filling) at once. I am asking for which python packages can manage this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is an example part of a large script where I extract values from a csv (will work for dbf, wont work for .xls or .xlrd aka excel sheet) and paste values onto a PDF using a searchcursor and reportlab to create and write to PDF.

```
import arcpy
import os
import arcgisscripting
from arcpy import mapping
import reportlab
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import legal
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter #PDF library used to merge PDF's
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
arcpy.env.workspace = "path workspace"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"path.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
pdfname = "name.pdf"
c = canvas.Canvas(pdfname, pagesize=landscape(legal)) #initiating canvas object to write to pdf
c.setFontSize(20)
pdfvalues = {}
for x in gp.SearchCursor(csv/dbf/featueclasstable):
    pdfvalues['value1'] = x.col1
    pdfvalues['value2'] = x.col2
    pdfvalues['value3'] = x.col3
for k,v in pdfvalues.items():
    if k == 'value1':
        c.drawString(x, y, "Value NO.1 = " + v) #x and y refer to locations on page
    elif k == 'value2':
        c.drawString(x, y, "Value NO.2 = " + v)
    elif k == 'value3':
        c.drawString(x, y, "Value NO.3 = " + v)
c.save()
```

EDIT - in addition to @artwork21 answer: check out my question [Arcpy mapping text element reset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/arcpy-mapping-text-element-reset)
*essentially I created a 'shell' mxd of text elements and for each iteration I went and replaced those text elements with the unique values for each iteration

Comment: Thank you very much, I am sure that this code took you to type in less than 5 minutes, whereas it would had taken me more than 2 days. Nevertheless, I will study this and customise it.

Comment: In my case, I am using a `DBF` with more than one record. When I use your code, my output `PDF` only lists the last record in the `DBF`. Is there a way to alter this code so that it loops through all the `DBF` records, writing one at a time to the report with `X` amount of space in between each record?

Comment: hmm not sure exactly what your problem is. post a question and and il try and help you. this is also old code that I used, I have updated it recently

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ModuleBuilder for GIS processing, I would recommend the following workflow:

1. Mock up a template map document layout to look like the pdf file text labels, boxes, and title.  You may use the text element on the draw toolbar to add the labels and boxes.  Add blank holder text within each text box, right click on it select Properties, select Size and Position tab and give a unique element name (this value will be updated by arcpy code)
2. Open up a text document save it as a .py extension and write the following, use da search cursor to iterate over excel or dbf table to pull certain values.  Crate a map reference to your template map doc and iterate over the layout elements using if conditional logic look for the unique text element name and update the blank value with what you pulled from the table.  Finally, once the layout is filled out use arcpy to export out the layout as a pdf.
3. Finally, drag and drop your .py into the model (at the end) and save your model.

You will have to do some web searching for arcpy concepts like, "run arcpy in standalone script", "use arcpy da search cursor", "update text elements using arcpy", and "export map to pdf using arcpy".  The .py file using arcpy will be executed at the end of the model and should produce a pdf of the text/info sourced from a table.

Comment: Thank you very much! This workflow is very hepful, as the time as I am trying to do this task on my own.